# What visa can you qualify for through double descent in UK

Tags: citizenship, uk-citizenship

I have been offered a job in the UK. I would like to know if I qualify for and if so what visa should I apply for. My mother lives in the UK with a British passport. She and my grandparents were British citizens. All born in South Africa. My great-grandparents were born in Scotland. My mother was registered at birth as a British citizen. I was born before 1983. I am female. Do I qualify for any visa?

Comment: To clarify, none of your grandparents were born in the UK? Because you might qualify for the ancestry visa if one of them was.

Comment: If your mother got citizenship by birth, I think you're automatically a citizen as well. More information here: http://www.workpermit.com/immigration/united-kingdom/british-citizenship-descent-or-otherwise You can also check if you're a citizen here: https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen

Comment: This question might also be helpful to you: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/do-i-have-british-citizenship-by-descent?rq=1

Comment: @shortyputting On the contrary, it seems that the mother is likely a British citizen by descent, meaning that her children, including Jen, would be British citizens only if born in the UK.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions

Comment: @shortyputting: British citizenship by descent could not be from the mother prior to 1983. However if the mother was a British citizen otherwise than by descent, the OP qualifies to register as a British citizen now. If the mother was a British citizen by descent, but the OP was registered at a British consulate within one year of birth, the OP also qualifies to register as a British citizen now.

Comment: You can become British citizen if either (1) your parent was British citizen and you were born in the UK, or (2) your parent was British citizen born in the UK, or naturalised, and you were born anyway. You can't become British citizen if your parent was a British citizen born outside the UK, and you were also born outside the UK.